# Why doesn't automatically create at relation table? (in mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
create table Board (
boardID     char(30) not null,
readLevel   tinyint not null,
writeLevel  tinyint not null,
PRIMARY KEY (boardID) ) engine=InnoDB character set=utf8;

create table Post (
postID          int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
title           char(50) not null,
content         TEXT not null,
writeDate       date not null,
readCount       int not null,
PRIMARY KEY (postID)) engine=InnoDB character set=utf8;

create table Save_Board_Post(
boardID   char(30) not null,
postID    int not null,
FOREIGN KEY (boardID) REFERENCES Board(boardID) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (postID) REFERENCES Post(postID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ) engine=InnoDB character set=utf8;

insert into Board (boardID, readLevel, writeLevel) values ('testBoard', 0, 0);
insert into Post  (title, content, writeDate, readCount) values ('testPost1', 'test', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ,0);

select * from Board where boardID='testBoard';
select * from Post where tile='testPost1';
select * from Save_Board_Post where boardID='testBoard';
```

I'm rookie in sql. and I'm not native about English.

So, Please forgive my English skills.

Here's my mysql code.

Last five lines are for test. And select from Board and Post is working fine.

But

```
select * from Save_Board_Post where boardID= 'testBoard';
```

It doesn't work. This code has no error. but there is no output result.

I guess it means no data in Save_Board_Post table.

I thought REFERENCES command is automatically creation data when insert parent table.

If it does not, please let me know how to automatically creation in relation data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not what `REFERENCES` does. All that your `REFERENCES` constraints mean is that every row that is inserted (manually) into the `Save_Board_Post` table must have a `boardID` and a `postID` that exist in the `Board` and `Post` tables. Nothing is inserted into that table automatically.

If you are trying to represent what board a post is in, the appropriate way to do this would be to make the board ID be a property of the post, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Post (
    postID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    boardID CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY (boardID) REFERENCES Board(boardID)
);
```

rather than having an entirely separate table just for that data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot automatically insert data in child table by inserting in the parent table. You got it right when you said it failed because there was no data in the table. Referential integrity exist to remove redundancy in a database. I dont think there is a way for you to automatically insert into the child table by inserting into a parent table. you have to do it manually.

Comment: fwiw, there is a way to insert automatically to the child table. -> see `CREATE TRIGGER [BEFORE|AFTER] INSERT INTO ..`

Comment: Thanks for the information. i guess am getting a bit rusty. The user mentioned that he/she is a rookie. Would you please explain better for our collective benefit? I have not worked with triggers before.